# graph theory: the degree of vertices in an hesse diagrem graph

Tags: graph-theory

In this picture you can see the hesse diagrem of $\subseteq$ over $P(\{x,y,z\})$

[image]

For the set $A$ with $k$ elements, $k>0$

look at the diagram as a graph, it's vertices are the members of $P(A)$

Show the graph is a regular graph (all vertices have the same degree)

what is the degree?

I know the answer is $k$, I just don't know how to prove it, please help.

Answer (score 2):

Each set $S\subseteq A$ is adjacent "upwards" to the sets having one extra element which isn't in $S$.  And it is adjacent "downwards" to the sets having one element of $S$ removed.  So $S$ is adjacent one way or the other to one set for each element of $A$, whether or not it is an element of $S$.  That is, every set is adjacent to $k$ other sets.